# Grails URL validation

Tags: grails, grails-validation

Why Grails see URLs without http:// (like www.google.com) as invalid?
Only http://google.com and http://www.google.com are ok.
Is there any way to fix that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read [RFC 1738 (Uniform Resource Locators)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), it is clear that the URL scheme (in your case, http://), is a full part of URLs. The scheme defines the meaning of the rest of the URL, and thus, can't be omitted. For instance http://www.google.com is definitely not the same ressource as https://www.google.com, and you should be aware of that when you save a link.

So URL like `www.google.com` **are not** valid, and Grails is right when it rejects them.

Fixing that should be easy if you know you expect an http URL:

```
new Object(url: 'http://' + url).save()
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I am using validations just with Command objects, not for Domain classes.